# VSCode Emmet: How to disable certain snippets

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, emmet

For example, in my html file, emmet thinks that the "var" keyword should be a tag on the first suggestion.

```
var -> <var></var>
```

I NEVER use that var, so I'd like to remove it so that the django var comes first.

```
var -> {{ }}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

There are some solutions:

- if you want to define a new shortcut for `var` keyword during coding, you can add a new custom snippet by command `Preferences: configure user snippets`, more details see: [Snippets in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) or [Emmet in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets)
- if you just don't want to use any of emmet abbreviation from VSCode default settings, you can disable it in `settings.json`:

```json
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "html"
],
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for because I do still want to use emmet, there's just one emmet snippet that I DON'T want to use.

Comment: Then you can use snippets. User-defined snippets  are always in higher priority.